# How to make DataTables able to filter on selected columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have the following JavaScript with DataTables.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

var columns = [
    {title: "Name"}, 
    {title: "Position"}, 
    {title: "Office"}, 
    {title: "Extn."}, 
    {title: "Start date"}, 
    {title: "Salary"}
];

// Footer construction
var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
    $tfoot.append("<th>");
}

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columns,
    initComplete: function (setting, json) {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    } 
    
} );
} );

var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];
```

```html
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see, when you run the code snippet, I can filter the every column with drop down list at the bottom.
But what I intend to do is only to apply the column on  *2nd (position) and 3rd (office) columns* . How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to have a dropdown list only for column 2 and 3 ? Unclear what you're asking .

Comment: @Hacketo: Yes. This is just example. Other cases I may use it for other column combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can specify an array with column indexes in a call to [`columns()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29) API method.

For example, to display filter in second and third columns only:

```
this.api().columns([1,2]).every( function (index) {
```

> **DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var columns = [
    {title: "Name"}, 
    {title: "Position"}, 
    {title: "Office"}, 
    {title: "Extn."}, 
    {title: "Start date"}, 
    {title: "Salary"}
];

// Footer construction
var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
    $tfoot.append("<th class='select-filter'>");
} 

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columns,
    initComplete: function (setting, json) {
        this.api().columns([1,2]).every( function (index) {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    } 
    
} );
} );

var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()) function pass an index parameter to the callback. 
You can use it to check if you want to add a filter or not.

```
this.api().columns().every( function (index) {
    if (index != 1 && index != 2) return;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var columns = [
    {title: "Name"}, 
    {title: "Position"}, 
    {title: "Office"}, 
    {title: "Extn."}, 
    {title: "Start date"}, 
    {title: "Salary"}
];

// Footer construction
var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
    $tfoot.append("<th class='select-filter'>");
} 

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columns,
    initComplete: function (setting, json) {
        this.api().columns().every( function (index) {
            // just continue if index 1 and 2
            if (index != 1 && index != 2) return;
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    } 
    
} );
} );

var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the js from -- `this.api().columns().every( function () {` to `this.api().columns('.select-filter').every( function () {`,
then add class "select-filter" to table-header:

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Position</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```